# sort a list of dict's with floats and int's into specific order

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary

i have a list of dict's eg

```
list = [{'route number': '996', 'happy customers': '0'}, {'route number': '123', 'happy customers': '4'}, {'route number': '321', 'happy customers': '0.00'}, {'route number': '456', 'happy customers': '5'}, {'route number': '856', 'happy customers': '8.760'}, {'route number': '555', 'happy customers': '1.1'}, {'route number': '565', 'happy customers': '0'}, {'route number': '784', 'happy customers': '3.010'}]
```

and i am trying to sort them by happy customers and if happy customers == 0 then sort by route number
i have tried this:

```
sorted_list = sorted(list, key = operator.itemgetter ("happy customers", "route number"), reverse = True)
```

output is

```
[{'route number': '856', 'happy customers': '8.760'}, {'route number': '456', 'happy customers': '5'}, {'route number': '123', 'happy customers': '4'}, {'route number': '784', 'happy customers': '3.010'}, {'route number': '555', 'happy customers': '1.1'}, {'route number': '321', 'happy customers': '0.00'}, {'route number': '996', 'happy customers': '0'}, {'route number': '565', 'happy customers': '0'}]
```

expected output:

```
[{'route number': '856', 'happy customers': '8.760'}, {'route number': '456', 'happy customers': '5'}, {'route number': '123', 'happy customers': '4'}, {'route number': '784', 'happy customers': '3.010'}, {'route number': '555', 'happy customers': '1.1'}, {'route number': '321', 'happy customers': '0.00'}, {'route number': '565', 'happy customers': '0'}, {'route number': '996', 'happy customers': '0'}]
```

i think it has something to do with

```
route number': '321', 'happy customers': '0.00'}
```

number on the end being a float 0.00 not just an int 0 but i dont know how to change it to make it work any help would be appreciated FYI list of dict's imported from a routes.txt file hence some numbers floats and some int's any ideas on how to make this work ?? or what i am doing wrong with the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use custom `key=` function, where you convert the strings to `float` and `int`:

```py
lst = [
    {"route number": "996", "happy customers": "0"},
    {"route number": "123", "happy customers": "4"},
    {"route number": "321", "happy customers": "0.00"},
    {"route number": "456", "happy customers": "5"},
    {"route number": "856", "happy customers": "8.760"},
    {"route number": "555", "happy customers": "1.1"},
    {"route number": "565", "happy customers": "0"},
    {"route number": "784", "happy customers": "3.010"},
]

out = sorted(
    lst, key=lambda k: (-float(k["happy customers"]), int(k["route number"]))
)
print(out)
```

Prints:

```py
[
    {"route number": "856", "happy customers": "8.760"},
    {"route number": "456", "happy customers": "5"},
    {"route number": "123", "happy customers": "4"},
    {"route number": "784", "happy customers": "3.010"},
    {"route number": "555", "happy customers": "1.1"},
    {"route number": "321", "happy customers": "0.00"},
    {"route number": "565", "happy customers": "0"},
    {"route number": "996", "happy customers": "0"},
]
```

---

EDIT: To convert the strings to numbers:

```py
lst = [
    {
        "route number": int(d["route number"]),
        "happy customers": float(d["happy customers"]),
    }
    for d in lst
]

out = sorted(lst, key=lambda k: (-k["happy customers"], k["route number"]))

print(out)
```

Prints:

```py
[
    {"route number": 856, "happy customers": 8.76},
    {"route number": 456, "happy customers": 5.0},
    {"route number": 123, "happy customers": 4.0},
    {"route number": 784, "happy customers": 3.01},
    {"route number": 555, "happy customers": 1.1},
    {"route number": 321, "happy customers": 0.0},
    {"route number": 565, "happy customers": 0.0},
    {"route number": 996, "happy customers": 0.0},
]
```

Comment: just checking but shouldn't the output be [{"route number": 856, "happy customers": 8.760}] not [{"route number": "856", "happy customers": "8.760"}]

Comment: @JAI The output is the same as `expeced_output` in your question. You can convert string to numbers afterwards.

Comment: @JAI See my edit.

Comment: can you please explain -float ? and -k ? why the need for -

Comment: please confirm -k and -float in lambda sub function is == reverse = True but only for the key value that is being sorted ?? not for the entire list eg.. if out = sorted(lst, key=lambda k: (k["happy customers"], k["route number"]), reverse = True)

Comment: @JAI `key=lambda k: (-k["happy customers"], k["route number"])` means I want sort by `happy_customers` reversed (descending), by `route_number` normally (ascending).

Comment: 1 more thing please i dont understand how the convert lst=[{"." : int(d["."]},{"." : float(d["."]} for d in lst works i am new to python and still learning and thought that anything = [{}] is a list or anything = "asd", is a touple and anything = 123 is int and anything = "hello" is a str can you please explain how this works ? i do understand that one liners for on the right is processed first